Possible to add custom description in pytest report, one per test class?
Ask: I want to be able to have a long description of a set of test cases appear in pytest's report output, defined at runtime, one description per test class (not per test function).
Scenario: I have a pytest test class similar to below:
  @pytest.mark.parametrize("year, expected_results", [("2022", "Something-2022"), ("2023", "Something-2023"), ("2024", "Something-2024")])
  class TestShortDesc1:
    @pytest.fixture(scope="function")
    def calculated(self, year):
      return f"Something-{year}"

    def test_short_explanation_1(self, year, expected_results, calculated):
      pass

    def test_short_explanation_2(self, year, expected_results, calculated):
      pass
    
    def test_short_explanation_3(self, year, expected_results, calculated):
      pass

When run via pytest, each test gets executed 3 times, once per parametrized value.  So my output will have 9 test runs.
What I want is to include something like this:
  class TestShortDesc1:
    def __init__(self):
      print("A bit longer description what this set of tests are about, printed once for all test functions in this test class")

Is this possible and if it is, how do I do this?  I know I cannot use init as that breaks stuff.

Does this help?

I did see that but it seems to be adding the comment to each test function, not one per test class.
